# Change initial view controller for target

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode-storyboard

I have a big Xcode iOS project.

This project contains multiple screens and starts on a debuging menu (View Controller).

What I want to do is to create a second target in my project.

With this target, I want to start to another ViewController.

Is there a way in the storyboard to set another initial view controller checkbox, but only for a target.

Comment: With target you mean another viewcontroller for users with iphone 5s and other for users with iphone 6?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to create different ViewController for each target selection. You can select target membership for different VCs

See below picture, it might help you to find out target selection in VC

[image]

Answer (score -1):

i have not tried this. But i found a similar question on stackflow. This might help you : 
[Is it possible to change 'is initial view controller' based upon Target?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15191167/is-it-possible-to-change-is-initial-view-controller-based-upon-target)